# Retrieve objets using a specific secret / configmap via client-go library

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I am trying to develop a simple controller using the [`client-go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) library.

There is a requirement that each time a secret and/or a ConfigMap is updated on my cluster, I perform a specific action on the objects using those Secrets / ConfigMaps.

I know how to watch for changes on specific objects using [informers](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/informers).

My question is whether it is feasible, by getting access to a Secret / ConfigMap to automatically list the objects (deployments, jobs, etc) that use them.

Comment: No, there is no api for listing who is using a specific Secret or ConfigMap

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to list all dependent objects of an object automatically in the manner you're describing.

However, you could have a controller that watches your objects of interest (e.g. deployments, jobs, etc.) and updates the `metadata.ownerReferences`of your secrets and configmaps with those objects that intends to use them.

While this is commonly done for GC purposes, these objects would then be "listed" when you do a `kubectl describe` on your secret or configmap.

> **metadata.ownerReferences**
>
> *List of objects depended by this object. If ALL objects in the list have
>        been deleted, this object will be garbage collected. If this object is
>        managed by a controller, then an entry in this list will point to this
>        controller, with the controller field set to true. There cannot be more
>        than one managing controller.*
>
> *OwnerReference contains enough information to let you identify an owning
>        object. An owning object must be in the same namespace as the dependent, or
>        be cluster-scoped, so there is no namespace field.*

Source

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#ownerreference-v1-meta